# how to get exception type in nested exception in Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, exception, apache-kafka, nested

I want to perform some action if my code gets an `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetOutOfRangeException`. I tried with this check

```
if(e.getCause().getCause() instanceof OffsetOutOfRangeException)
```

but am still getting a SparkException, not an OffsetOutOfRangeException.

```
ERROR Driver:86 - Error in executing stream
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 11, localhost, executor 0): org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetOutOfRangeException: Offsets out of range with no configured reset policy for partitions: {dns_data-0=23245772}
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseFetchedData(Fetcher.java:588)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:354)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1000)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:938)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.poll(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:271)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:231)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:393)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)`
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetOutOfRangeException: Offsets out of range with no configured reset policy for partitions: {dns_data-0=23245772}
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseFetchedData(Fetcher.java:588)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:354)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1000)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:938)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.poll(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:271)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:231)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
```

Comment: @anandbabu - 1) That's not the full stack trace.  There are no stack frames!  Show us the full stack trace ... including all of the "caused by" subsidiary traces.  2) Put the extra information into your question, not into a comment.  (Use the "edit" button!)

Comment: We are asking to see a real stacktrace for a reason.  That is ... to see if what you have really has the `OffsetOutOfRangeException` nested in it.  Yes, we can see the name in the message, but that doesn't prove anything.

Comment: To people who are guessing answers, the `instanceof` and `e.getClass()` versions are testing the same thing.  The real issue is whether `OffsetOutOfRangeException` is actually a nested exception of whatever `e` is ... and how deeply it is nested.   That's why we **need** the stacktrace.

Comment: How can this question be so negatively noted ? It's not a stupid question at all, and more than that : everyone has is own answer, and they are not all the same !

Comment: @vmrvictor - Please read carefully what I wrote.  I wrote "they are testing the same thing".  That is, they are testing the class of the exception. I did not write "they are the same test".

Comment: *"It's not a stupid question at all, and more than that : everyone has is own answer, and they are not all the same !"* - I didn't down vote.  But I suspect the reason people downvote is that the Question does not provide the necessary information to answer.  Specifically, it doesn't provide a stacktrace, and the OP **ignored** repeated requests for a stacktrace.

Comment: @Marc The OP hasn't done what Stephen and I asked for -- show the `catch` block and show the full stack trace. Simple requests. We shouldn't have to make wild guesses to answer the question.

Comment: And at the end of the day, we have an OP who has code that works (apparently) without understanding why.  And future readers will be totally unenlightened.  The real purpose of downvotes is to filter out questions that won't help the general readership; i.e. to direct the *curation* of the StackOverflow knowledgebase.  The downvotes are justified from that perspective.

Comment: I cannot explicitly catch  SparkException or OffsetOutOfRangeException, because  these exception throw by nested classes. I have already mentioned my if condition inside my catch block in the question. Not sure, why this question not clear. @teeman got the question and able to suggest me the solution.

Comment: The reason we wanted to see the full stack trace was so we could see the "Caused by:" line, which tells us that you could check if `getCause()` is an `OffsetOutOfRangeException`. Without that line, @teeman12's answer was a guess. We don't want to be guessing, and you shouldn't ever code just by taking random guesses and seeing if they work. It's always best to fully understand a problem and the solution to it so you know exactly why the solution works and the previous attempts don't.

Comment: Or more plainly, if I ask for a piece of important information, and my request is ignored, I downvote. Thank you for now adding the stack trace. I've reversed my vote.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try the below condition:

```
e.getCause().getClass().equals(OffsetOutOfRangeException.class)
```

Comment: This is, to all intents and purposes, the same as what the op tried in the question.

Comment: it worked perfectly. I'm able to compare the OffsetOutOfRangeException in my catch block and applied some action. Thank you very much for knowledge sharing.